# Accent after post page

Tags: character-encoding, diacritics

I have problems with accents. I have a form and i can visualize in correct way the accent in the words: Piñones (in html Pi& ntilde;ones)
When i post the form in the next page the word appear as: PiÃ±ones.

I have same tag between head: meta charset="utf-8"

Any suggestion?

Thanks you.

Comment: I think we need more information about what you are doing.  Are you talking about a web site?  (I see "post the form")

Comment: Hello. Yes is a form in my website. Never happened before. When i submit the form all words with accent are lost. The header of thew page is the same for both pages. (meta charset="utf-8").

Comment: `meta charset` is nice. However, it is: 1) overridden by the Content-Type header if the server passes it (possibly even if that header lacks the charset clause). 2) a declaration of the actual encoding. So, it should be the encoding that the server/website is using. Ã± matches up exactly with interpreting the UTF-8 bytes for ñ as ISO 8859-1. That's called mojibake, which is a form of bug. Explore [here](http://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx). We can't answer your question unless you [edit] your question with some details.

Comment: We also need to know the technologies that are handling the data.  What are you using to build the web pages?  Is the data going into a database before coming out again?  Everything may or may not cause a problem with the characters.  The meta tag is only information for the recipient and doesn't _force_ anything to follow that encoding.